# Reference: Sufficient condition of absolute continuity w.r.t. Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, absolute-continuity

currently I am reading the Brownian Motion Book from Peter Mörser and Yuval Peres. In section about occupation measures and Green's functions they state the following theorem.

Let $(B_s)_{s \geq 0}$ be Brownian motion and let $t>0$. Then define the following occupation measure
$$
\mu_t(\cdot) = \int^{\infty}_0 \mathbf{1}_{B_s \in \cdot} ds \quad (\cdot \subset \mathbb R).
$$
This definition is fine, the claim of the proposition is that $\mu_t$ is absolutly continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.

$\textbf{Here comes the question}$: At the beginning of the proof they give the following sufficient condition: It sufficies to prove that for $\mu_t$-almost every $x \in \mathbb R$ one has
$$
\liminf_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu_t(B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))} < \infty
$$

I have covered a course on integrations/measure theory and stochastic process, but this sufficient condition is foreign to me. Does anybody have an explanation/reference?

Comment: this is clear from results in Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_: If $\mu$ has non-trivial singular part then that limit is $+\infty$ almost everywhere[$\mu$].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rudin's RCA (the chapter on Differentiation) it is shown that if $\mu\perp \lambda$ then  $\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))}  \to \infty$ as $ r\to 0$  for almost all $x$ (w.r.t Lebesgue measure). Since any positive measure is the sum of a singular and  an absoluetly continuous measure it follows that this limit relation holds whenever $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase your statement. We know that by Lebesgue decomposition the relationsship $$\mu_t = \mu^{a}_t + \mu^{s}_t$$ where $\mu^{a}_t \ll \lambda$ and $\mu^{s}_t \perp \lambda$ holds. Hence it is left to prove that ${\mu^{s}_t}$ is trivial. Here I am not 100% sure. Again be Rudin 7.15 we know that for our Borel positive measure $\mu_t = \mu^{a}_t + \mu^{s}_t$ we have $\mu_t \perp \lambda \iff \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{\mu(B(x,r)}{\lambda(B(x,r)} = \infty$, hence we prove that the latter is not true, then  we are done. Is this correct?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent $\mu_t$ is positive because integral of a non-negative function is non-negative.

Comment: Ah yes obviously, I guess the fact that is borel is also obvious? One needs to prove that for each $x \in A$ there exists a n.b.h. $U_x$ such that $\mu_t(U_x) < \infty$. If not then the brownian motion stays in a tiny n.b.h. $U_x=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ the whole time, which it clearly does not.

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent Rudin does not make any such finiteness assumption. Any countably additive $\mu_t$ defined on the Borel $\sigma-$ algebra (vanshing at the empty set) taking value in $[0,\infty]$ is fine in Rudin's Theorem.

Comment: For the Lebesgue decomposition theorem 6.10 that is true, however for the second step (7.15) he states the theorem only in terms of positive Borel measures, doesn't he?

Comment: You seem to have a different definition of  a Borel measure. See 2.15 in Rudin's book. Any countably additive set function on the Borel $\sigma-$ algebra is called a  Borel measure. @a.s.graduatestudent

Comment: That is correct, I didnt check his definition, which I should've have. Thanks for the great answers, do you know some other good "canonical" examples where one has to prove this absolutly continuity by also proving that we have a trivial singular part in the measure, i.e. common exercises regarding this technique, maybe outside of Rudin?